# CLI stopped working error

Tags: laravel-5

I get "CLI stopped working" error when i press the upload button.I used the sample code from one of the website to upload file into the database column.      I use Laravel 5.2.39. command used: php artisan serve

Code:(Only test version)

### Form.blade.php

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="/upload_file">
{{ csrf_field() }}
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

### Routes.php

(Not an ideal place to code this but it is only for file upload test purpose)

```
  Route::get('/upload_form', function()
    {
       $data['files'] = Attachment::get();
       return View::make('form', $data);
    });

    Route::post('/upload_file', function()
    {
    $rules = array(
        'file' => 'required|mimes:doc,docx,pdf',
        );

    $validator = Validator::make(Request::all(), $rules);

if(Request::hasFile('file'))
{
   $f = Request::file('file');
   $att = new Attachment;
   $att->name = $f->getClientOriginalName();
   $att->file = base64_encode(file_get_contents($f->getRealPath()));
   $att->mime = $f->getMimeType();
   $att->size = $f->getSize();

   $att->save();

   return Redirect::to('/upload_form');
}

});
```

Has anyone encountered this issue? Need help.

Comment: are you sure that this code is for laravel 5, because in Laravel 5 `Input` class is no-more, instead of that to retrieve value from post you should use `Request` Class. I think it is causing error

Comment: Thanks. I get same error even with Request class.

Comment: can you update your question with $request class

Comment: you should use this class with in controller

Comment: thank you very much. It works now!.  I moved the code from routes.php to controller as you suggested.